# Bypassing IOErrors and HTTP Exceptions in Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I have a large scraping job that I am trying to run, using Selenium and PhantomJS in Python. It throws a couple of different errors after having run correctly for about 24 hours. Tested this a couple of times. Obviously, any new code added is a bit hard to test, as I have to wait for 24 hours to see it anything was solved. So, I was wondering if anyone with more experience could take a look at this piece of code and see if it seems ok. What I am trying to do is keeping the while loop going in spite of errors from the browser.

```
while something:
    try:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    except httplib.HTTPException:
        print 'HTTPException'
        time.sleep(20)
        pass
    except IOError:
        print 'IOError'
        time.sleep(20)
        pass
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code looks fine. You can use `except (httplib.HTTPException, IOError) as e:`, `print type(e).__name__` to combine the handlers, and you can drop the `pass`:

```
while something:
    try:
        driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, document.body.scrollHeight);")
    except (httplib.HTTPException, IOError) as e:
        print type(e).__name__
        time.sleep(20)
```

I'd use the [`logging` module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/logging.html) to provide logging information here; the `logger.exception()` function would include the exception and traceback in the output:

```
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

# ...

except (httplib.HTTPException, IOError) as e:
    logger.exception('Ignoring exception, sleeping for 20 seconds')
    time.sleep(20)
```

Comment: Thanks! But if I drop the ´pass´, won't the loop stop if encountering an error?

Comment: @textnet: no, `pass` means *do nothing* and is only required if the suite would otherwise be empty.

Comment: Still, even with the `logging` strategy, it throws the same error:

Comment: @textnet: That exception was triggered by the line `old_length = len(driver.page_source)`; was that line part of the `try...except` suite? It is not in your question.

Comment: @textnet: and note that `logger.exception()` logs the full trackback for an exception when caught, the exception is still handled.

Comment: @Martin_Pieters: Adding the socket.error did not solve it. Now trying to run it again, after having moved the line that triggered the error inside the try...except suite.

Comment: @textnet: yes, `socket.error` is a subclass of `IOError` so it should not need to be explicitly added.

Comment: @textnet: you *do* need to put all lines you want protecting inside the `try` suite.

Comment: Moving all lines that are talking with the webdriver inside the `try:` section works, I think. The loop is not broken. However, the 'Ignoring exception...' is never printed in the Sublime Text build window.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/73137/discussion-between-textnet-and-martijn-pieters).